# Unable to set text on dynamic buttons

Tags: android, button, settext

I am new to android.
I generated the dynamic buttons in a new row of table layout on click of every button.
But, whenever I click on button, I should display some text on the button.
But I'm unable to settext for the except last buttons (for clarity observe image).
Please help me out friends.

[Please find the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSA5k.png)

This was the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.wordtxt);
    final String a=et.getText().toString(); 
    final char[] arr=a.toCharArray();   


    // Capture button clicks
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg) {
            //Hiding the Key board
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)
                   getSystemService(getApplicationContext().INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
               inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
                       InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);

            final TableLayout table=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tbl);


            //Toaster Ex
            int wordCount=et.getText().length();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Word Count is"+wordCount, 4000).show();

            int k=0;
            final TableRow  tr;
            tr = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
            table.addView(tr);
            final Button btn;
            btn = new Button(MainActivity.this);
            btn.setText("");
            btn.setId(k);
            tr.addView(btn);
                btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {                        
                        EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.wordtxt);
                        String a=et.getText().toString(); 
                        char[] arr=a.toCharArray();                         
                        int rowcount= table.getChildCount();                            
                    if(rowcount<arr.length)
                    {
                        if(rowcount==1)
                        {
                                EditText et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.wordtxt);
                                String a1=et1.getText().toString(); 
                                char[] arr1=a1.toCharArray();

                                int id=(v.getId());
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"If ID is "+id,2000).show();                         

                                btn.setText(String.valueOf(arr[id]));
                                btn.setEnabled(false);
                                TableRow tr = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
                                int x=0;
                                int y=0;
                                while(x <rowcount+1)
                                {
                                    if (x % 9 == 0) {
                                      tr = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);                                       
                                      table.addView(tr);
                                    }
                                    Button btn1 = new Button(MainActivity.this);
                                    btn1.setText("");
                                    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
                                    btn1.setId(x);
                                    tr.addView(btn1);   
                                    x++;                                
                                }
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            EditText et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.wordtxt);
                            String a2=et2.getText().toString(); 
                            char[] arr2=a2.toCharArray();                               
                                    int min = 0;
                                    int max = rowcount-1;       
                                    Random r = new Random();
                                    int i1 = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
                                    int id=(v.getId());
                                    if(id==i1)
                                    {

                                            Button tx = (Button) findViewById(i1);
                                            Button(MainActivity.this);
                                            tx.setText(String.valueOf(arr[i1]));

                                            tx.setEnabled(false);
                                    }

                                    TableRow tr = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
                                            int x=0;
                                            int y=0;
                                            while(x <rowcount+1)
                                            {                                                       
                                                if (x % 9 == 0) {
                                                  tr = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);                                                   
                                                  table.addView(tr);                                                  
                                                }

                                                Button btn1 = new Button(MainActivity.this);
                                                btn1.setText("");                                                   btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
                                                btn1.setId(x);
                                                tr.addView(btn1);   
                                                x++;                                
                                            }
                        }
                    }


                    }
                });


                table.setShrinkAllColumns(true);

        }
    });


    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

Thank you.

Comment: Show some code, please.

Comment: @Udi ldan, can you please provide me any solution?

Comment: Can you show the complete Activity?

Comment: @Udi Idan, I had posted the complete one.

Comment: Please put some effort into formatting your code, remove the extraneous empty lines, indent blocks properly, remove the imports (we don't need them, we can guess what they are). Also as to your errors, don't use final, you're using it incorrectly. Don't initialize your variables just anywhere.  Practice java using these exercises http://codingbat.com/java and read a book for Java beginners. I am sorry to say that you won't be able to move forward if you don't study the java language a little bit more first. We just can't correct all those mistakes for you.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk  , I agree with you. I'm very beginner.